# Get min date and first text of another column with min date

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have three columns Action Date,Text,Performance Date.

I want to fetch Min Action Date , Text entered for min Action Date and max Performance date.
Here are the details:

```
Create Table Performance (
  PerformanceId   int identity primary key,
  ActionDate      datetime,
  Notes           varchar(500),
  PerformanceDate datetime, 
  jobId           int
)
```

I want to get Action Date as 2018-10-16 09:59:00.000, Text as Job to be on hold , performance date 2018-10-26.

```
Id    ActionDate     Notes               PerformanceDate  JobId
1     2018-10-16     Job to be on hold   2018-10-26       10
2     2018-10-26     Job to be Released  2018-10-16       10    
3     2018-10-05     Job hold back       2018-10-11       10
```

Multiple entries of Performance is done against a job. I want to show a summary report showing the first entry done which is min Actin date and the not associated with that date and the max PerformanceDate entered

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the database schema (as `create table ...` statement) and some representative data in the table. Also explain which result you want and the rules behind it.

Answer (score 0):

At first select these two dates:

```
SELECT min(action_date) From table_name
UNION
SELECT max(performance_date) From table_name
```

And then get text of these two:

```
SELECT text, action_date From table_name
WHERE action_date IN (
    SELECT min(action_date) From table_name
    UNION
    SELECT max(performance_date) From table_name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use subqueries, you can use window functions:

```
select distinct jobid,
       min(action_date) over (partition by jobid),
       max(performance_date) over (partition by jobid),
       first_value(notes) over (partition by jobid order by action_date)
from t
where jobid = 10;
```

Another method is:

```
select top (1) t.*,
       max(performance_date) over (partition by jobid)
from t
where jobid = 10
order by action_date;
```